# Impossible to serve WebP images using CloudFlare?

Tags: nginx, cdn, cloudflare

I want to optimize some images on my site using WebP format.

Webp images are highly compressed jpegs and pngs with the help of algorithm developed in Google.

However, webp images can be displayed only in modern Chrome and Opera.
If browser supports webp it specifies `image/webp` in `Accept` HTTP header.

It is good idea to check in nginx if browser supports webp format and if webp version for image exists on disk and if so - serve webp image, if not - serve default image.

For example:

`http://example.com/dog.png`, `Accept: image/webp, image/png, image/jpeg`. nginx must send `dog.png.webp`

`http://example.com/dog.png`, `Accept: image/png, image/jpeg`. nginx must send `dog.png`

A little bit more explanation can be found in this nginx configuration https:// github.com/igrigorik/webp-detect/blob/master/nginx.conf and https:// github.com/kavu/sprockets-webp#nginx

That's ok. But I am using CloudFlare CDN to speed up asset delivery.

With such image serve conditions we must add header `Vary: Accept` so cacheing in browser and proxy will work properly. But there is a problem! CloudFlare supports only `Vary: Accept-Encoding`. This is described [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/217343117-What-headers-can-I-vary-the-cache-on-?input_string=Is%20Vary%3A%20Accept%20supported%3F).

Clients will get version of image which was cached by CloudFlare first (webp or regular) and if client doesn't supports webp it will not see image and it is terrible.

Is there any solutions?

Comment: I can set `Cache-Control: private` for webp images so CloudFlare will not cache them and request will go to origin where I can check for webp support and send necessary version.

Answer (score 1):

With the example of having `dog.png` and `dog.jpg`.

- Have your backend serve a `/dog` (without any file extension) which will always respond with `Cache-Control: private` and thus be never cached by the CDN.
- Your backend will now always get hit for that url, and can analyze the headers like the `Accept` header, and decide if the browser needs `png`/`jpg` or if you can use more advanced format like `webp` [(Firefox, Chrome)](https://caniuse.com/#feat=webp), `JPEG 2000` [(Safari)](https://caniuse.com/#feat=jpeg2000) and `JPEG XR` [(IE9+)](https://caniuse.com/#feat=jpegxr).
- Now the backend forwards (`301` `Moved Permanently`) to either `dog.png` and `dog.jpg` or the converted `dog.webm`, `dog.jp2` and `dog.jxr` as needed.
- Those static image files are served with appropriate caching headers to be cached by the CDN.